# How to define custom shape, as click-able area for anchor tag? (cross-browser)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, anchor, shapes

Is there any way to have custom shape as click-able area for anchor tag?
Of course cross-browser version (IE +9)
I know we have `shape` attribute for anchor tag, but this one is not supported by IE.

**Update**:

I want only the blue area become click-able:

[image]

Comment: Do you want it as non-rectangle or non-circle?

Comment: A I said, Custom shape I mean, polygon, `polygon`

Comment: SVG would be the way to go...or just use an image. Depends on the actual  shape requirement.